# Unnest methods within super

Tags: java

Please consider the following class:

```
class MyClass extends Parent {
    private AnotherClass property;

    public MyClass(int value) {
        super(new AnotherClass(value));
        this.property = new AnotherClass(value);
    }
}

class AnotherClass {
    /* Implementation not shown */
}

class Parent {
    /* Implementation not shown, and may not be changed */
}
```

Without changing the constructor parameters, (example: `MyClass(AnotherClass value)`), how could I structure this so that `new AnotherClass()` is not called twice?

The following is an example of something that does not work:

```
public MyClass(int value) {
    AnotherClass anotherClass = new AnotherClass(value);
    super(anotherClass);
    this.property = anotherClass;
}
```

It raises an error saying that the call to super must be the first line.

I'm creating something that requires me to double dispatch, and I may not change how `MyClass` is instantiated. (`new MyClass(0)`). I may not touch the super class either.

Is it possible to only call AnotherClass once?

Comment: give the superclass a method that returns AnotherClass

Comment: @Leo Sorry I should have mentioned that I cannot touch the super class. I have mentioned that within my post.

Comment: Probably having a `getInstance()` method in `MyClass` could help.

Comment: Well, I can imagine a *really* bad (and probably useless) solution involving methods with side effects, but you probably really don't want to do that.

Comment: @kai I've done this already and it says `cannot reference anotherClass before supertype constructor has been called`.

Comment: Oh, what the heck. What happens if you make a `static` `getAnotherClass()` method that sets `property` and then returns it? To be honest, I'm not sure if it'd work, and to make it work you'd probably need to tweak it a bit.

Comment: @kai If `anotherClass` is an instance field (which it must be as a local variable cannot be declared prior to the call to `super()`) then you *can not* use in an explicit constructor call.

Comment: @DaveChen reflection is an option?

Comment: @Leo Isn't reflection an expensive operation? I'm trying to cut back on method calls.

Comment: @DaveChen it seems there are a lot of restrictions in your problem that are not evident (injection, reflection...) ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that cause `super()` has to be called on the first line. That said, 
you can use dependency injection and instantiate `AnotherClass` before you call `new MyClass(new AnotherClass())`. Then the constructor will look like this:

```
public MyClass(AnotherClass a) {
    super(a);
    this.property = a;
}
```

In case you cannot change `MyClass` you can wrap it with a wrapper class and apply the same "trick".

Comment: Wouldn't it also work to overload constructor ```public MyClass(int value) { this(new AnotherClass(value));}``` ?

Comment: @DaveChen and how is the answer you accepted different than mine ?

Comment: Sorry, just noticed actually. I initially thought that you were asking me to instantiate MyClass as `MyClass myclass = new MyClass(new AnotherClass())`. (Which I didn't want to do). After a re-read, it's the same answer (and yours was quicker). Thanks.

Comment: sorry, I also did not notice that you were suggesting the same as my answer.  I though you were simply suggesting changing the existing constructor.  I will add a credit to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Move it to use two constructors

```
public MyClass(int value) {
    this (new AnotherClass(value));
}

public MyClass(AnotherClass a) {
    super(a);
    this.property = a;
}
```

**Note**

This is also suggested by @alfasin

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
private static AnotherClass temp;

public MyClass(int value) {
    super(temp = new AnotherClass(value));
    this.property = temp;
    temp = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all let me fix compilation errors.

```
Class MyClass {
```

is wrong. you should write

```
class MyClass {
```

instead.

Second, when you call `suprer(something)` from constructor of your class you actually invoke the constructor of super class that obviously must exist. Otherwise you will get compilation error. Since all classes in java implicitly extend `java.lang.Object` (unless other based class defined) and `java.lang.Object` does not have constructor that is able to get argument of type `AnotherClass` your line `super(new AnotherClass())` cannot be compiled.

And the third, call of constructor of super class *must* be the first line of constructor. Otherwise creation of instance may be inconsistent since sub class may use state of super class.

So, the following code will compile and work.

```
class MyBaseClass {
    protected MyBaseClass(AnotherClass ac) {
        // some initialization code
    }
}

class MyClass extends MyBaseclass {
    private AnotherClass property;

    public MyClass(int value) {
        super(new AnotherClass(value));
        this.property = new AnotherClass(value);
    }
}
```

I hope that this answer helps.

Comment: It was only quick pseudocode, I have edited the post to reflect proper Java syntax.